new roof built on the house now the wall is about 5 in too Short from reaching the roof can we fill it in with cement
Can we use cement to fill the Gap in the wall up on top of the vertical wall 5-in Gap to the roof

This sounds very strange, lots the new roof wasn't done properly. You could do with including pictures

And some pics would help...
